# Stopping objectweb asm from replacing unreachable code with athrow

Tags: java, bytecode

Solved, this code does the replacement : https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/MethodWriter.java#L1382

Solution is to use an ifeq(false) to jump the dead code instead

I'm trying to inject some unreachable code into a method using objectweb asm. However it keeps replacing the instructions with athrow

For example I have this method:

```
public static boolean isTurkeyDay() {
    iconst_1
    ireturn
}
```

I attempt to change it to:

```
public static boolean isTurkeyDay() {
    goto L1
    nop
    nop
    :L1
    iconst_1
    ireturn
}
```

by running it through:

```
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    Label l1 = new Label();
    mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, l1);
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.NOP);
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.NOP);
    mv.visitLabel(l1);
    return super(mv);
}
```

My actual output ends up being

```
public static boolean isTurkeyDay() {
    goto L1
    nop
    athrow
    :L1
    iconst_1
    ireturn
}
```

Is there anyway to tell Objectweb not to replace my instructions with athrow? I would like to leave the dead code in place. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm by no means a bytecode expert, but that naked `athrow` (no exception object on the stack) looks wonky to me.  Did you write a dead-code removal analyzer as shown in the ASM documentation?

Comment: No I didnt do anything beyond what is about. However it has been solved. This is the code responsible for it https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/blob/master/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/MethodWriter.java#L1382 the solution im using is to do a if(false) before the dead code isntead of a goto

Comment: Interesting. I always wondered how ASM handled dead code when generating stack maps. Technically speaking, `if false` doesn't allow you to embed dead code, it just tricks the analyzer into thinking the code is live. Anyway, I wrote an answer explaining this in more detail.

Comment: @JimGarrison: who said there isn’t an exception on the stack? Since it’s dead code, it’s perfectly safe to assume that there is an exception on the stack at its beginning…

Answer (score 4):

The reason that ASM does this is the need to generate stack map frames. Historically, there was no problem with including dead bytecode - it would just be ignored by the verifier. However, with the introduction of stack map verification, every point of non-linear control flow requires a stack map frame, and the code is processed by the verifier.

This causes problems if you are generating stack maps for arbitrary bytecode. For example, consider the following bytecode

```
goto LWHATEVER 
; dead code
iload_0
aload_0
```

There is no possible stack map that would make this bytecode valid because the code loads register 0 as both an int and an object. With inference verification, this is no problem because the verifier never processes the dead code in the first place, but with the stack map verifier, all the code is processed in a single linear pass, whether it is reachable or not.

Therefore, in order to solve this problem, ASM just replaces the dead code with a series of `nop`s followed by an `athrow`. This ensures that a) there is a valid stack frame that can be generated for it (specifically, one with a single exception on the stack) and b) the dead code does not appear to jump anywhere else, which would further confuse the stack map verifier. This is why there's an athrow at the end instead of just using all nops.

As for the if false "solution", it's fine if that works for you, but it's not a 100% solution. The reason it works is because the verifier ignores condition values and assumes that every possible branch can be taken. Therefore, your code is considered live. However, the corollary of this is that it must have valid types and control flow, just as if the code were actually reachable. Likewise, ASM will see that it is live code and just use the normal type checking procedure to generate the stack frames. However, you'll get an error if you try to put invalid bytecode under the if false branch, since it is considered live.

The only real solution to embed arbitrary dead code in a method is to not use stack maps in the first place, which means setting the classfile version to 50.0 or below and telling ASM not to generate stack maps. Alternatively, you can use the Krakatau assembler, which gives you low level control over the resulting bytecode, at the expense of not automatically generating stack frames.

Comment: Of course, `iload_0; aload_0` is inconsistent and thus incompatible to stack maps. However, even with potentially valid dead code, calculating stack frames would be hard, as it would imply going *backwards* through the code to find a frame that would be a compatible starting point. So you *can* have dead code with ASM and stack maps, as long as you provide the frames *manually*, just like with Krakatau, instead of letting ASM calculate them.